# stacked group column chart in highcharts example

Tags: highcharts

I'm going to prepare a stacked column charts report using highcharts. The problem is my data types are different.

[Please, view image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFDqQ.png)

Could you help me create a chart like image. please

Comment: I posted answer, it should work for you. If it works for you then accept it.

Comment: Look at this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gup3mund/. Hope it helps.

Comment: d_Paul, your demo work to me, thank you su much for your help. really you was a big help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using Stacked Group in Highchart by handling data section properly.

Here, I tried to build same chart as you required. You can handle legend and other of the chart.

This should help you. I also created fiddle demo which you can access using below link.

Fiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/t4u8b8co/1/

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },

  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: [
      ['19603', '19666'], '19603', '19603'
    ]
  },

  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Good or Bad'
    }
  },

  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      stacking: 'percent'
    }
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [244, 23, 4],
    stack: '19603'
  }, {
    name: 'John',
    data: [306, 522, 546],
    stack: '19603'
  }, {
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [376],
    stack: 'female'
  }, {
    name: 'Janet',
    data: [174],
    stack: 'female'
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: @osantander If it works for you then accept and up-vote it.